# Debug Java Applet jar file in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, jar

I have a compiled jar file which is a compiled applet.  I have the parameters and name of the class with the init method to start the applet.

I have installed jd-eclipse and would like to debug the applet in eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

It should be pretty straightforward to do. Assuming at least Eclipse Galileo:

- Create a project in Eclipse and add your applet jar(s) to its build
  path. Alternatively you may choose to add the applet jar(s) to the
  build path of an existing project.
- Right-click your project, select Run As->Run Configurations Select
  Java Applet in the left hand pane and click the New button at the top
  of the pane

[image: Eclipse Run-As Configuration - Applet]

- At the top, fill out a name for the new Run configuration, then on the
  Main tab click to Search for your applet class.
- On the Parameters tab, fill out all parameters from your existing
  Applet HTML page.
- Optionally, fill out any additional information you want the Applet
  to have when it runs, on the other configuration tabs
- When done, click Apply, then optionally Run to fire off the test
  right away.

Good luck!